# Find and reduce decimal numbers contained in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a very long string containing several geographic coordinates expressed in decimal degrees (example: `+12.324333333`, `-34.245322222`). I need to modify the entire string with Python in order to reduce the digits after the decimal point .

These coordinates need first to be found and then changed.

Which is the fastest and easiest way ?

**EDIT**

This is an example of what I need to do.

**Original string :**

```
‘… { "type": "MultiPolygon",
     "coordinates": 
      [ 
        [ 
          [
            [ 29.051803589000372, 9.103446961000429 ],
            [ 29.053974152000308, 9.100263596000389 ],
            [ 29.052606582000124, 9.101751327000443 ]…’
```

**Modified string:**

```
‘…{ "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": 
    [
      [
        [ 
          [ 29.05, 9.10 ],
          [ 29.05, 9.10 ], 
          [ 29.05, 9.10 ]…’
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `modify the entire string with Python in order to reduce the digits after the decimal point`? Example?

Comment: We need to see the input format and the wanted output format.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Comment: Do you want the number truncated, or rounded?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import re
for n in re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", yourStr):
    yourStr = yourStr.replace(n, str(round(float(n), countDecimals)))
```

If you don't want to change your initial string copy it and then use replace. countDecimals for your example is 2.

**UPDATE**

From IDLE

```
>>> countDecimals = 2
>>> yourStr = '…{ "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 29.051803589000372, 9.103446961000429 ], [ 29.053974152000308, 9.100263596000389 ], [ 29.052606582000124, 9.101751327000443 ]…'
>>> import re
>>> for n in re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", yourStr):
    yourStr = yourStr.replace(n, str(round(float(n), countDecimals)))


>>> yourStr
'…{ "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 29.05, 9.1 ], [ 29.05, 9.1 ], [ 29.05, 9.1 ]…'
>>>
```

**UPDATE 2**

problem is that for 29.085363456418179
this code `>>> float('29.085363456418179')` return
29.08536345641818

You can use Decimal

```
from decimal import *
```

and

```
str(round(Decimal(n), countDecimals))
```

instead of

```
str(round(float(n), countDecimals))
```

Also I want notice that @stranac offered perfect solution with other regexp in one line

```
re.sub(r'([-+]?\d*\.\d{2})\d+', r'\1', yourStr)
```

Comment: I believe it should be `yourStr = yourStr.replace(n, str(round(float(n), countDecimals)))`, since `str.replace` returns a copy.

Comment: yeah you are right, I'm going edit it

Comment: Thanks Ray, it works almost perfectly. 
However, sometimes it does not behave correctly, like is this case:

yourStr = '"features": ["type": "Feature", "properties": { "STA_CODE": "81", "STATE": "Warrap" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", [ 29.085363456418179, 9.750404249641861 ], [ 29.082658973000207, 9.751562640000088 ],'

I don’t’ know where the error lies, but I think that modifying a little bit the expression proposed by @Alex, your script would work:

    r"([+-]?\d+\.\d+)\s*,\s*([+-]?\d+\.\d+)"

Comment: The whole thing could be simplified to `re.sub(r'([-+]?\d*\.\d{2})\d+', r'\1', yourStr)`, if rounding is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

That string looks like JSON. If it is indeed valid JSON, you can use the json module to do this.
A simplified example:

```
>>> import json
>>> original = """
... {
...   "type": "MultiPolygon",
...   "coordinates": [[ 29.051803589000372, 9.103446961000429 ],
                      [ 29.053974152000308, 9.100263596000389 ]]
... }
... """
>>> data = json.loads(original)
>>> data['coordinates']
[[29.05180358900037, 9.10344696100043], [29.053974152000308, 9.100263596000389]]
>>> data['coordinates'] = [[round(v, 2) for v in coordinate]
                           for coordinate in data['coordinates']]
>>> changed = json.dumps(data)
>>> changed
'{"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[29.05, 9.1], [29.05, 9.1]]}'
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I had made my answer before I saw example in question, I didn't know that it's json string. But anyway with regexp it's more universally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex for matching the coordinates:

```
 ([+-]\d+\.\d+)\s*,\s*([+-]\d+\.\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about, truncating to two decimals

```
result = re.sub(r"(\d+\.\d\d)\d+", r"\1", subject)
```

It was subsequently pointed out to me that this solution was also posted in a comment by @stranac that I did not see shortly before I posted it in an answer.

Comment: It has been offered already @stranac in comments

Comment: I had not seen his in that form when I devised mine -- although I do see my post marked about 30 minutes after his.  I only saw posts and comments that were not truncating the extra decimals.

Comment: @DanielGrankin I will acknowledge that in my answer.